# When user click on notification it does not start particular activity when app is in foreground

Tags: android, push-notification

When user click on notification it does not start particular activity. its working when well when user kill the app then restart.when user again send notification when user in app foreground user click on notification but particular activity is not open.

**Cases**

A when the user initially start app and notification comes then user click on a notification that time particular activity is opening.When I kill the app and restart again notification come click on notification then open particular activity open. but now my app in foreground/background notification come click on the notification that time that particular activity is not opening.

My activity is a base activity which in my I've define multiple conditions like

- when about us notification comes then redirect to about us fragment
- when chat messaging notification comes and then redirect to chat
  fragment

**Code**

```
Notiifcationmessage service class TvamFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
{

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private Intent notificationIntent;
    private PendingIntent contentIntent;
    private String urlstring="";
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e("push", "data: " + remoteMessage.getFrom().toString());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            acquire(getApplicationContext());
            release();
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String notificationMsg = "",messageType="";


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new     JSONObject(data.get("message"));
                notificationMsg = jsonObject.get("message").toString();
//                sendNotification(notificationMsg, false,false);
                messageType=jsonObject.getJSONObject("type").getJSONObject("data").getString("msg_type");
                message=jsonObject.getJSONObject("type").getJSONObject("data").getString("message");
                urlstring=jsonObject.getJSONObject("type").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

                if (data.containsKey("hc_type") && data.containsKey("chat_id")) {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, true, false,"");
                } else if (jsonObject.getJSONObject("type").has("type") && jsonObject.getJSONObject("type").getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("BROADCAST")) {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, false, true,messageType);
                } else {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, false, false,"");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("message", data.get("message"));
                notificationMsg = data.get("message").toString();
                if (data.containsKey("hc_type") && data.containsKey("chat_id")) {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, true, false,"");
                } else if (data.containsKey("type") && data.get("type").equalsIgnoreCase("BROADCAST")) {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, false, true,messageType);
                } else {
                    sendNotification(notificationMsg, false, false,"");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Preferences.setPreferences(PreferencesConstants.DEVICE_TOKEN, token);
    }


    public void sendNotification(String notificationMsg, boolean isFromHelpCranch, Boolean isBroadcatsMessage,String messageType) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Hello";// The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        if (isFromHelpCranch) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BaseActivity.class).putExtra("from", "notification");
            //    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tvam_logo)
                        //   .setContentTitle("Tvam (त्वम्) - Vedic Astrology & You")
                        //  .setContentTitle("Tvam (त्वम्) - Vedic Astrology & You")

                        .setContentText("[Tvam (त्वम्)]: " + notificationMsg)
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    } else if (isBroadcatsMessage && !isFromHelpCranch) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BaseActivity.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).
        putExtra("from", "notification_3").
        putExtra("type", messageType).
        putExtra("url", urlstring).
        putExtra("content", message);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tvam_logo)
                        //  .setContentTitle("Tvam (त्वम्) - Vedic Astrology & You")
                        .setContentText("[Tvam (त्वम्)]: " + notificationMsg)
                        //  .setContentText(notificationMsg)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BaseActivity.class).putExtra("from", "notification_2");
     //   notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tvam_logo)
                        //  .setContentTitle("Tvam (त्वम्) - Vedic Astrology & You")
                        .setContentText("[Tvam (त्वम्)]: " + notificationMsg)
                        //  .setContentText(notificationMsg)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    //    mNotificationManager.notify();
    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}


@SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
public static void acquire(Context context) {
    if (wakeLock != null)
        wakeLock.release();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/);
}

public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null)
        wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock = null;
}
```

Comment: Please don't format regular sentences as code. Now I have to scroll horizontally to read what you wrote. I'm lazy, I want to help, but I don't want to scroll to right and left. I will prefer another question.

Comment: @Eugen pechanec I knew but I'm new in development.please help me to resolve this issue